# Can't singin into SkyDrive account. WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, authentication, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, onedrive

I am making SkyDrive integration in my app for Windows phone. Every time after login screen in signInButton_SessionChanged it gives me e.Status  = Unknown with e.Error = "". 
I tried download some examples for SkyDrive integration
http://rabeb.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/using-skydrive-in-your-windows-phone-applications-part-1/
, but it gives the same result.

```
    private void signInButton1_SessionChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Live.Controls.LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
          {
              session = e.Session;
              client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
              infoTextBlock.Text = "Signed in.";
          }
        else
         {
             infoTextBlock.Text = "Not signed in.";
              client = null;
         }
     }
```

I tried to change App ID ond Live account also, but nothing helps. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if in application settings at [Live Connect Developer Center](https://account.live.com/developers/applications) you haven't specified that it is a Mobile client app:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it is a mobile client app. I have made a hard reset for device, and problem seems to be solved.